# Deploying a VB.Net application that includes SSRS reports to a customer's computer

Tags: vb.net, reporting-services, deployment

We created a VB.Net application which includes SSRS reports that runs on my development computer.

Do you know of a step by step guide that steps us through deploying the reports on our customer's computer?

We will be installing SQL Server 2012 Express Advanced on the target computer then configuring the reporting services then installing the application. The last part we need help with is to install the reports themselves on the target computer.

Comment: are the report definitions in the app, or on the report server?  It's a winforms app (not a web app), right?

Comment: The reports are deployed on the development computer server. The datasource for the reports are also deployed on the development computer server and this is a WinForms app. We are needing a way to get the reports imported onto the customer's computer which is also the report server.

Comment: what's the file extension of the report definitions: .rdl or .rdlc?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Publishing Reports to a Report Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159270.aspx)